# where we use estimation and detection in communication system?

Tags: filters, digital-communications, estimation, detection, equalizer

I read from the book that we use estimation when we are dealing with analog signal or continuous random variable and the term detection when the transmitted signal is a discrete value even if a received signal is continuous.
I want to know if in digital communication we use both estimation and detection and in which step we do these process.
Also, when we do equalization in the process.

Comment: Sounds like the book was not about communications. Because outside of the book's context one could easily define detection as either the process, that includes estimation, or as a pure estimation. Could you please share the title?

Comment: John R Barry chapter 7 starting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry too much about defining these terms too precisely, because they are used in many contexts with slightly different meanings.

In very general terms, "estimation" is the calculation of a signal parameter, for example the phase, the mean, the PSD, etc. In other words, you have a signal, possibly noisy or distorted, and you want to find something about it.

"Detection" is concerned with whether you actually have a signal or not; think about radar, where you send a pulse, and wait to see if you *detect* the reflection. Since recovering the information from a PAM signal is based on the same principle (i.e. matched filtering), in digital communications it is common to say that transmitted symbols are *detected*.